# Firebase is not updating when page re-direct is used

Tags: javascript, firebase

Below is my javascript function, which isn't updating firebase, when i am using the code for page re-direct (`window.location.href`). However, it's properly updating firebase, when `window.location.href` is removed.

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function bookappnt() {

        var appname = document.getElementById("app-name").value;

        var ref = new Firebase("https://dermaenbgtt1233.firebaseio.com/"); 
        var usersRef = ref.child("Appointment-Details");

        usersRef.push({
        applicationname: appname
        });

        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";

        }
</script>

<input type="text" id="app-name" class="user" placeholder="Name">
<input type="submit" value="Book appointment" onclick ="bookappnt()">
```

Comment: `windiw`. Please look at your JS console :)

Comment: Deleted my answer, also noticing the comment here. Did not realize it was inappropriate to answer for a typo, have seen quite a few on here.

Comment: Apologies for the typo while posting the code. Unfortunately, when i corrected typo of "windiw" to "window", page is getting re-directed. But it's not updating firebase. I have tried several ways, but either it's updating firebase, or just re-directing.

Comment: @AbhishekKashyap you're aborting said update.

Comment: As @KevinB pointed out, you're not waiting for the `push` call to finish before redirecting. The browser will not let requests continue after navigation.

Comment: I searched a lot but unable to find how to wait for the push to be completed, before using `window.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved with `.then()`. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        function bookappnt() {

        var appname = document.getElementById("app-name").value;

        var ref = new Firebase("https://dermaenbgtt1233.firebaseio.com/"); 
        var usersRef = ref.child("Appointment-Details");

        usersRef.push({
        applicationname: appname
        }).then( user => {

window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";

});
}
</script>
```